# Why are address generated by CPU called "logical" address?

Tags: operating-system

During compile time and load time address binding logical address is same as physical adsress. My question is that, if logical and physical address are identical in compile time and load time address binding then why do we call it logical address? Shouldn't the term "logical address" be used only in execution time binding

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are 2 types of bindings:

**1) Dynamic/Hardware-Based/Runtime Binding:**
Here the MMU (Memory Management Unit) is responsible for translating the logical addresses. It is assumed that each program is loaded at logical address zero. When the program starts running the OS decides where should it reside in the actual physical memory and sets a special register called base register to the offset in the physical memory. Then each logical address is translated in this manner:

> Physical Address= Logical Address + Base Register Value.

*Note that if you look at the assembly code for the program the addresses are logical thus they don't change if you recompile.

**2) Static/Software-Based Binding:**
At compile time the OS knows where the process will reside in the physical memory. Thus the addresses in the compiled/ assembly code will be the actual physical addresses and note that these addresses might change if we recompile.

**FINAL NOTE:** I think that static binding is not used nowadays .. thus logical addresses are 100% different than the physical addresses (dynamic binding).